# Generate XML response in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

I have a controller class, I'm expecting it to display the `.xml` response of model class which is annotated with `@XmlRootElement`. The Controller class method which displays all the student list is ,

```
@RequestMapping("studentlist")  
   public @ResponseBody  
   StudentList getStudentList() {  
   List<student> studentList = new ArrayList<student>();  
   studentList.add(new Student(3, "Robert", "Parera", "robert@gmail.com", "88"));  
   studentList.add(new Student(93, "Andrew", "Strauss","andrew@gmail.com", "89"));  
   studentList.add(new Student(239, "Eddy", "Knight", "knight@gmail.com",  "79"));  
   return new StudentList(studentList);  
 }  

}
```

i have added the `@ResponseBody` ,but still the class is not displaying the `.xml` response This is my `web.xml`.

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javasample.common.controller" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

  </beans>
```

Please advice what is missing. I also have model class which is properly annotated with `@XMLElement` ,`@XmlRootElement` etc. Kindly advice as I'm new to *Spring MVC*.

Comment: First, you're specifying Spring 3.0 in your XML. Second, describe what *is* happening: Are you getting incorrect output? An error message?

Comment: I'm just getting plain response and not xml,the output is below           3RobertParerarobert@gmail.com4AndrewStrauss8978767878

Comment: You mention that you have your model class annotated with JAXB annotations. Is this also true for the StudentList class?

Comment: yes its a model class which is annotated       @XmlRootElement(name = "student-list")  
public class StudentList {  
  
 private List<Student> studentList;  
  
 protected StudentList() {  
 }  
  
 public StudentList(List<Student> studentList) {  
  this.studentList = studentList;  
 }  
  
 @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(name = "student")  
 public List<Student> getStudentList() {  
  return studentList;  
 }
 
}